# css3 padding, percentages and box-sizing

Tags: css, width

I have two columns one is 60% and one is 40%. Both need to have 20px padding on them. What is the best way to calculate this without using the box-sizing property? Do I do it in % or ems?

Is box-sizing property a good method to use here?

Comment: Provide us a fiddle code of your HTML and CSS.

Comment: This is the perfect use case for `box-sizing: border-box`. You can use [this polyfill](http://html5please.com/#box-sizing) for older versions of IE. Also, remember to include the `-moz-` and `-webkit-` prefixes for Firefox and older versions of Safari.

Comment: I thought older ie versions used this box model anyway?

Comment: @welovedesign Only in quirksmode, so I think IE 6 & 7 would be an issue, but they are basically dead by now.

Answer (score 0):

you can use calc function like this:

```
width: calc(100% - 80px);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: nice idea and would use it but the support is not as good as I would like. I think box-sizing is the way

Answer (score 0):

To answer your original question, unless you **must** have 20 pixels for some reason, use percentages for the padding and margins and subtract it from the width.  I'll use ems for the top/bottom padding and margins because that's what I do IRL.

```
.myclass_1 {
     width: 56%;
     margin: 1em 1%;
     padding: .5em 1%;
     display: inline-block;
}
.myclass_2 {
     width: 38%;
     margin: 1em auto;
     padding: .5em 1%;
     display: inline-block;
}
```

The problem that border-box was developed to solve is that **borders** will not take a percentage for their width, which makes it impossible to put pixel-perfect borders into a fluid layout. It's more convenient for padding, since you don't have to do a lot of math, but at least it works; whereas with borders, there is no solution except to approximate.

What I do to accommodate border widths, and what you might want to try as a fall-back for older browsers, is to set a minimum width on the containing box, then shave a half percent off the width to allow for border width.  Then just play with it in your screen, until it fills the minimum sized window without breaking the design.

Needless to say, this will also work if your padding must be 20px but you want a fluid display, as a graceful degradation for browsers that don't support newer box-sizing.

BTW, if you don't have borders, there is a "box-sizing: padding-box" style, although I'm not sure if it has any advantage over border-box.  I'm with you on calc() -- it's still too buggy even where supported.